# How to implement on slickgrid a custom column which is editable and the editor is a custom select editor?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

My slickgrid has editable columns. One of the columns is a custom column because I want to display and edit the name of that object. In order to edit that name I needed a custom select. In order to display the data in grid correctly I set on grid options dataItemColumnValueExtractor, so data is displayed correctly, but the problem is when I edit that column or I add a new row, the value selected from the select is not displayed on grid. Please see below the code:

```
var gridOptions = {
editable: true,
enableAddRow: true,
enableCellNavigation: true,
asyncEditorLoading: false,
autoEdit: true,
rowHeight: 30,
dataItemColumnValueExtractor: function getValue(item, column) {
    var values = item[column.field];
    if (column.fieldIdx !== undefined) {
        return values && values[column.fieldIdx];
    } else {
        return values;
    }
}
```

};

```
var alternatesGridColumns = [
      { id: "DetailId", name: "DetailId", field: "DetailId", width: 0, minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 0, cssClass: "gridColumnHidden", headerCssClass: "gridColumnHidden" },
      { id: "Alternate", name: "Alternate", field: "Alternate", fieldIdx: 'Name', width: 220, cssClass: "cell-title", editor: selectAlternates, selectvalidator: requiredFieldValidator },
      { id: "Conversion", name: "Qty Per", field: "Conversion", width: 200, editor: Slick.Editors.Text, validator: requiredFieldValidator },
      { id: "Id", name: "Action", field: "Id", width: 80, resizable: false, formatter: Slick.Formatters.DeleteSelects }
```

];

```
initAlternatesGrid = function (selections) {
alternatesGrid = new Slick.Grid("#AlternatesGrid", selections, alternatesGridColumns, gridOptions);
alternatesGrid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.CellSelectionModel());
alternatesGrid.onAddNewRow.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    data = alternatesGrid.getData();
    var item = args.item;
    if (!validateSelection(args.item)) {
        return false;
    }
    alternatesGrid.invalidateRow(data.length);
    data.push(item);
    alternatesGrid.updateRowCount();
    console.log(data);
    alternatesGrid.render();
});
```

}

```
function selectAlternates(args) {
var $select;
var defaultValue = "";

this.init = function () {
    option_str = "";
    $.each(List, function (index, value) {
        option_str += "<OPTION value='" + value.Text + "'>" + value.Text + "</OPTION>";
    });
    $select = $("<SELECT tabIndex='0' class='editor-select'>" + option_str + "</SELECT>");
    $select.appendTo(args.container);
    $select.focus();
};
this.destroy = function () {
    $select.remove();
};

this.focus = function () {
    $select.focus();
};

this.loadValue = function (item) {
    var fnDicve = args.grid.getOptions().dataItemColumnValueExtractor;
    defaultValue = (fnDicve ? fnDicve(item, args.column) : item[args.column.field]) || "";
    $select.val(defaultValue);
    $select.select();
};

this.serializeValue = function () {
    return $select.val();
};

this.applyValue = function (item, state) {

    item[args.column.fieldId] = state;
};

this.isValueChanged = function () {
    return (!($select.val() == "" && defaultValue == null)) && ($select.val() != defaultValue);
};

this.validate = function () {
    if (args.column.validator) {
        var validationResults = args.column.validator($select.val(), args);
        if (!validationResults.valid) {
            return validationResults;
        }
    }
    return {
        valid: true,
        msg: null
    };
};
this.init();
return $select.val();
```

};

How could I make this work? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `fieldId` is not part of your column definition. I guess you meant to refer as `fieldIdx`. Note: the set `field` property will show up to your grid unless you set a formatter referring to `fieldIdx`.

your code:

```
this.applyValue = function (item, state) {
    item[args.column.fieldId] = state;
};
```

try this instead.

```
this.applyValue = function (item, state) {
    item[args.column.field] = state;
};
```